# Zend redirector and module as subdomain

Tags: zend-framework, module, routes, subdomain

I have configured route for cms in my project to cms.m.dev

```
resources.router.routes.cms.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.cms.route = "m.dev"
resources.router.routes.cms.defaults.module = "cms"
resources.router.routes.cms.chains.admin_default.route = "/:controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.cms.chains.admin_default.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.cms.chains.admin_default.defaults.controller = "dashboard"
```

but now I have problem with redirector:

```
$this->_redirector->gotoUrl('/doctor/edit/');
$this->_redirector->gotoSimple('edit', 'doctor', 'cms');
```

When I call it like this it redirects me to to **m.dev/cms/doctor/edit** instead of **cms.m.dev/doctor/edit** . Is there any way I can tell redirector that module is subdomain, not subdirectory?

UPDATE: I have created route:

```
resources.router.routes.cms_doctor_index.route = "/doctor/"
resources.router.routes.cms_doctor_index.type =     "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
resources.router.routes.cms_doctor_index.defaults.module = "cms"
resources.router.routes.cms_doctor_index.defaults.controller = "doctor"
resources.router.routes.cms_doctor_index.defaults.action = "index"
```

But it still redirects me to m.dev/doctor/

Answer (score 0):

You should try `gotoRoute()` to specify that you want the redirector to use your special route

```
gotoRoute  ( 
    array $urlOptions = array(),  
          $name = null,  // $name = "m.dev"
          $reset = false,  
          $encode = true   
 )
```

I haven't tested this, but it *should* work.

Comment: `resources.router.routes.cms.route = ":module.m.dev"` and use `gotoRoute()` as advised above